# How to add "onclick" event to .appendChild in same function?

Tags: javascript

here is my first question on stack**overflow**.
I was doing some research, and I was not able to find a solution or better to say understandable question for me.
What I was trying to do is, creating a list of task. After using appendChild(x) which is button I would like to directly create "onclick" event with function for this button.
I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

Here is my code so that you guys can see directly what I have done.

```
let newTask = [];



function addTask(){
    let someTask = document.getElementById('task').value;
    newTask.push(someTask);
    tasks.innerHTML="";
    for( i= 0; i < newTask.length; i++){
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let done = document.createElement('button');
        let no = document.createElement('button');
        done.innerHTML="Done";
        no.innerHTML="Move to reminder list";
        li.innerHTML=newTask[i];
        tasks.appendChild(li);
        tasks.appendChild(done); 
        tasks.appendChild(no);       
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not put event handlers on every element (and don't need too). You should investigate [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate),

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will read through link which you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add this:

```
 tasks.appendChild(li);
 tasks.appendChild(done); 
 tasks.lastChild.onclick = function () { // your code }
 tasks.appendChild(no);   
 tasks.lastChild.onclick = function () { // your code }
```

Comment: ***If*** you were going to add the event handler to each element, the correct approach would be to use `element.addEventListener("eventName", functionReference)`. `onXyx` properties shouldn't be used.

Comment: I completely agree

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response!! I will try this. I'm still lvl noob :D